# Qt5 android application

Tags: android, qt, qt5

in my android application i want to show a list of links.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    LinkListModel social_links;
    social_links.get(content_category::social);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &social_links);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is my .qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        width: 640
        height: 480

        model: myModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 25
            width: 100
            Text { text: "modelData: " + title }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't show my model class as it does not matter for my problem.
When I want to run the application in the emulator i get the following error message and the application aborts:

```
W/EGL_emulation( 6582): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/Qt      ( 6582): items\qquickview.cpp:518 (void QQuickViewPrivate::setRootObject(QObject*)): QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem. 
W/Qt      ( 6582): 
W/Qt      ( 6582): If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you 
W/Qt      ( 6582): loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur. 
W/Qt      ( 6582): 
W/Qt      ( 6582): To load files with 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', use the 
W/Qt      ( 6582): QDeclarativeView class in the Qt Quick 1 module. 
W/Qt      ( 6582): 
F/libc    ( 6582): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x2a43e000 (code=1), thread 6582 (.example.AKBApp)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QQuickView` only supports loading of root objects that derive from `QQuickItem`. `ApplicationWindow` derived from `QQuickWindow`. You should use [QQmlApplicationEngine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html) instead of `QQuickView`.

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

LinkListModel social_links;
social_links.get(content_category::social);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", &social_links);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
return app.exec();
```